# How do I turn an Array into String?

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I'm trying to add my data from a form into my database. But when I click the submit button, it shows me this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\stock\php_action\createAppointment.php on line 16

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\stock\php_action\createAppointment.php on line 16
{"success":true,"messages":"Successfully Added"}
```

I've searched and landed on this site. It told me to use implode but I do not know where to place it and when I looked at the function it's for echoing an array into a string but I want to add the data to the database instead of echoing it.

Here is my code for the **line 16** thing:

```
<?php   
require_once 'core.php';

$valid['success'] = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array(), 'appointment_id' => '');
// print_r($valid);
if($_POST) {    

  $appointmentDate          = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['appointmentDate']));  
  $patientName              = $_POST['patientName'];
  $physicianName            = $_POST['physicianName'];
  $description              = $_POST['description'];



    $sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (appointment_date, patient_name, physician_name, description) VALUES ('$appointmentDate', '$patientName', '$physicianName', '$description')";
    }
    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    $valid['success'] = true;
                    $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Added";  
                } else {
                    $valid['success'] = false;
                    $valid['messages'] = "Error while adding the members";
                }

// /if $_POST
// echo json_encode($valid);
    $connect->close();

    echo json_encode($valid);

// /if $_POST
```

**line 16** is this line:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (appointment_date, patient_name, physician_name, description) VALUES ('$appointmentDate', '$patientName', '$physicianName', '$description')";
```

edit:

I've checked my DB and it adds values (although i added empty data except for the top one which has 's' in the description) but physician name and patient name are the ones that are arrays.

This is my code for physician name (same with patient name):

```
<?php
    $physicianSql = "SELECT * FROM physician WHERE physician_active = 1 AND physician_status = 1";
    $physicianData = $connect->query($physicianSql);

    while($row = $physicianData->fetch_array()) {                                           
        $selected = "";
        if($row['physician_id'] == $orderItemData['physician_id']) {
            $selected = "selected";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }

        echo "<option value='".$row['physician_id']."' id='changePhysician".$row['physician_id']."' ".$selected." >".$row['physician_name']."</option>";
    } // /while 

?>
```

here is the screenshot of the DB: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM7FH.png

Comment: One of the variables in the query is an array, probably `$description`. However, you code has a serious problem, even without errors. Search for 'SQL-injection'.

Comment: You will have a lot of issues trying to put post data into a database, it isn't quite as simple as converting to a string, you will need to take care of a bunch of special characters, I would suggest an easier option is that you base64 encode the string and insert that into the database.

Comment: Please visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Right now your code is not safe at all and really vulnerable. Please use prepared statements whenever you've queries with user inputs.

Comment: Okay thanks guys, i'll look into your advices. I'm pretty new to php and I just learned it a few months ago.

Comment: @NolanKr Thats no problem. I just really recommend you to learn prepared statements. Its really easy if you understand the basics of PHP and not difficult at all... Once you understand how to use them, just use them everywhere.

Comment: @Twinfriends Oh I just read! sql injection is dangerous- thanks for the warning! I'm learning a lot.

Comment: Hello again!

I've tried submitting an empty form (except for physician name and patient name). When I checked my DB it says they're both arrays. I tried placing a value in description and it seems to be working fine


screenshot here:
https://i.imgur.com/QJubWjL.png.

Comment: please use var_dump($appointment,$patientName,$physicianName,$description ); and see which on is array

Comment: I'm missing a part of your code. Could you post your `<select>` tag?

Comment: Hello @MCEmperor and everyone else. I'm so sorry for the late reply. I've found the solution. I just turned all physician_id into physician_name and then removed the '[]' so it won't be an array. It worked but I don't know if it's a good thing to do. If you still need the select tag I can post it. hehe